# C# ODBC Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, odbc

I'm trying to connect to an Access 2007 database (.accdb) with a .net console application. I setup a System DSN in ODBC Manager. 
This is how I'm setting up the connection:

```
conn = new OdbcConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "DSN=HU-FU";
conn.Open();
```

On my development machine it works perfectly, but today I tried to install it on a client machine and I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR [IM006] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed
```

Anyone has an idea what could be the problem?

---

Here is the ODBC trace source:

```
UPSShipmentServ 1454-6f0 ENTER SQLDriverConnectW 
  HDBC                0x00424070
  HWND                0x00000000
  WCHAR *             0x69938B34 [      -3] "******\ 0"
  SWORD                       -3 
  WCHAR *             0x69938B34 
  SWORD                       -3 
  SWORD *             0x00000000
  UWORD                        0 <SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT>

UPSShipmentServ 1454-6f0 EXIT  SQLDriverConnectW  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
  HDBC                0x00424070
  HWND                0x00000000
  WCHAR *             0x69938B34 [      -3] "******\ 0"
  SWORD                       -3 
  WCHAR *             0x69938B34 
  SWORD                       -3 
  SWORD *             0x00000000
  UWORD                        0 <SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT>

DIAG [IM006] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed (0)
```

UPSShipmentServ is the name of my app. But this sadly does not mean anything to me...

---

One more addition to the question. I checked the Access driver's (ACEODBC.DLL) version on both machines and mine is much newer than the client's. Could it be the problem? Is there any way to update his driver?

Thanks.

Comment: have you set up DSN on the client machine?

Comment: You'd need to know what SQLSetConnectAttr attribute is failing. Enable tracing in the ODBC administrator then try and connect again then look in the trace to see what attribute is failing to be set.

Comment: The DSN is set on the client machine, that's not the issue.

Comment: are you sure that is all that is in the trace file?

Answer (score 3):

Okay guys, I have to apologize for this question...

I know what was the problem. It's a stupid error. In the ODBC manager when I setup the DSN I did not select properly the accdb file. So my program failed cause there was no db file selected for the DSN.

So next time, if you see this error, make sure your DSN is set up correctly. Thanks for the replies anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am off, but I usually refer to Access bd files directly (this is not necessary the right way):

```
    String dbPath = "c:\access.accdb";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbConnection mycon = new OleDbConnection();
    mycon.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + dbPath + ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=thePassword;";
    cmd = mycon.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = Query;
    mycon.Open();
```

Comment: I can try this, but I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

go into your odbc data source administrator on the client computer your installing it on
and add the datasource 'HU_FU'